# check one checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="event-types[]" value="family" />
<input type="checkbox" name="event-types[]"  value="adult" />
<input type="checkbox" name="event-types[]" value="children"  />
```

and I want to check at least one is selected

but this always equals 0

```
alert($("[name='event-types']:checked").length);
```

Comment: You're missing the square brackets

Comment: I could have sworn I tried with and without. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sD8M6/))

```
alert($("[name='event-types[]']:checked").length);
```

The attribute selector compares the given value with the element's attribute so it must match exactly.

Comment: you may have to escape `[]` in the attribute value like `alert($('[name="event-types\[\]"]:checked').length);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny in my jsFiddle it works without escaping.. do you know exactly when will the escaping be needed?